# Searching sets of numbers in random numbers using binary search algorithm

Tags: c#

My Code below is not working, not giving me any output. It was working well when I asked users to enter set of numbers and find within. But when I tried to search within random numbers, it is not working at all. Can anyone help me figure out, what did I do wrong, because program build successfully. It just won't giving the correct output.

```
 {
   class program
   {
    public class BinarySearch
    {
        public static int Search(int[] list, int x, int lower, int upper)
        {
            if (lower == upper)
            {
                int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
                if (x == list[middle])
                    return middle;
                else if (x > list[middle] )
                    return Search(list, x, lower, middle - 1);
                else
                    return Search(list, x, middle + 1, upper);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            int key;       
            int index;    
            int low = 0;
            int high = 1000; 

            int[] list = new int[1000];
            Random RandomNumber = new Random();


            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                list[i] = RandomNumber.Next(1, 1000);
            }
            foreach (int j in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", j);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("...................................................\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number to be searched in the list.");

            key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            index = Search(list, key, low, high);
            Console.WriteLine("...................................................\n");
            if (index == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Key {0} not found", key);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Key {0} found at index {1}", key, index);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Binary search mimic the human way of searching a vocabulary. Try to search an unsorted one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sorting the "list".

Binary search requires the list to be sorted by the same rules you're using `<` and `>` inside the binary search algorithm, otherwise it will not work.

So sort the numbers in the array and the binary search should work much better.

Note, I think you've reversed the partition statements inside the numbers. If `x > list[middle]`, then you need to search the upper part, not the lower part. This alone will not explain or fix your problem though, first you need to sort the numbers.

Finally, know that `0` is a valid index into the array, which means that you won't be able to distinguish between "not found" and "found at index 0" with your code.

My advice: Find an existing implementation of binary search and copy that, or at least use it as a source for inspiration.

Comment: It did work better when I sorted the numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Of course it did, the whole concept of the binary search algorithm revolves around the knowledge that the input elements are sorted.